# How to kill a process synchronously on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process

When I call kill() on a process, it returns immediately, because it just send a signal. I have a code where I am checking some (foreign, not written nor modifiable by me) processes in a loop infinitely and if they exceed some limits (too much ram eaten etc) it kills them (and write to a syslog etc).

Problem is that when processes are heavily swapped, it takes many seconds to kill them, and because of that, my process executes the same check against same processes multiple times and attempts to send the signal many times to same process, and write this to syslog as well. (this is not done on purpose, it's just a side effect which I am trying to fix)

I don't care how many times it send a signal to process, but I do care how many times it writes to syslog. I could keep a list of PID's that were already sent the kill signal, but in theory, even if there is low probability, there could be another process spawned **with same pid** as previously killed one had, which might also be supposed to be killed and in this case, the log would be missing.

I don't know if there is unique identifier for any process, but I doubt so. How could I kill a process either synchronously, or keep track of processes that got signal and don't need to be logged again?

Comment: Perhaps have a signal handler in the process to be killed that writes to the file when receives SIGINT and then kills self?

Comment: but this process is watching foreign processes, not only these I wrote and can modify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you could do a "synchronous kill", you still have the race condition where you could kill the wrong process. It can happen whenever the process you want to kill exits by its own volition, or by third-party action, after you see it but before you kill it. During this interval, the PID could be assigned to a new process. There is basically no solution to this problem. PIDs are inherently a *local* resource that belongs to the parent of the identified process; use of the PID by any other process is a race condition.

If you have more control over the system (for example, controlling the parent of the processes you want to kill) then there may be special-case solutions. There might also be (Linux-specific) solutions based on using some mechanisms in `/proc` to avoid the race, though I'm not aware of any.

One other workaround may be to use `ptrace` on the target process as if you're going to debug it. This allows you to partially "steal" the parent role, avoiding invalidation of the PID while you're still using it and allowing you to get notification when the process terminates. You'd do something like:

1. Check the process info (e.g. from `/proc`) to determine that you want to kill it.
2. `ptrace` it, temporarily stopping it.
3. Re-check the process info to make sure you got the process you wanted to kill.
4. Resume the traced process.
5. `kill` it.
6. Wait (via `waitpid`) for notification that the process exited.

Comment: damn... this is all so much true. you didn't make me happy :) but thanks for good answer

Answer (score 1):

This will make the script wait for process termination.

```
kill $PID
while [ kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null  ]
do
     sleep 1
done
```

`kill -0 [pid]` tests the existence of a process

Comment: Did you test that? I do not think that you want the [ and ] around the kill command. I am pretty sure you just do `while kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Should the process block when it can kill more than just the one PID?

Comment: That can hang if another process is spawned with the old pid.

Comment: thanks for answer, it doesn't matter I am talking about c, this code is fine as well, just it doesn't work 100% - if there is another process spawned with same pid between the two calls of kill, it would keep checking, but not the same process

Comment: This will run into an infinite loop if the process exists and it doesn't respond to SIGTERM (the first kill).

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for most processes that aren't debuggers or processes being debugged in a debugger.

- Use `ptrace` with argument `PTRACE_ATTACH` to attach to the process.  This stops the process you want to kill.  At this point, you should probably verify that you've attached to the right process.
- Kill the target with `SIGKILL`.  It's now gone.
- I can't remember whether the process is now a zombie that you need to reap or whether you need to `PTRACE_CONT` it first.  In either case, you'll eventually have to call `waitpid` to reap it, at which point you know it's dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this in C you are sending the signal with the `kill` system call.  Rather than repeatedly sending the terminating signal just send it once and then loop (or somehow periodically check) with `kill(pid, 0);`  The zero value of signal will just tell you if the process is still alive and you can act appropriately.  When it dies `kill` will return `ESRCH`.

Comment: what happens if between the two calls of kill(pid,0); the process die and another one is spawned with same pid? this is extremely unlike, but possible. in this case esrch wouldn't be returned

Comment: How are you avoiding that *now* by just bombarding the process with signals?

Comment: I am not avoiding it in this moment, I want to know how to avoid it :) hence I am asking here... btw "bombarding" is just side effect caused by this whole issue, I would happily solve it any other way if there was some

Comment: I mean, it's not purposefully repeatedly killed. It happens because the process is dying slower than my program executes the checks in a loop. And because my program can't know if it already did send the signal to this process (no really unique identifier exists in linux) and it didn't die since last time it got sigkill, it receives another sigkill... and then again, and again... it's a bug, not a feature

Comment: My thinking is that you *do* have a reasonable (if not unique) identifier - whatever was the criteria for killing the process in the first place e.g. too much memory consumption as mentioned above.  You can signal to see if the process hasn't been killed within X seconds.  If it has, fine, you are done.  It if hasn't, does the process still still meet the death penalty criteria?  Whether it is a new process with the same pid or the one you already tried to kill, if the process is exhibiting the behavior you want to bill, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: it does matter because I am also writing this to syslog. And in case of process that is dying 20 seconds, I am getting thousands of syslog lines telling it was killed

Comment: I am not sure if I don't understand or if we are talking past each other.  You are in charge of what you log.  Log it the first time as "kill signal sent" or whatever.  When the kill is confirmed (no such pid) you are done.  If it isn't dead after X time, check to see if it is still kill worthy and either send another kill signal and log it again or whatever makes sense.  Either way just by checking you reduce thousands of log lines to a couple.

Comment: "Log it the first time ..... when the kill is confirmed" << here is the problem - the kill can NEVER BE CONFIRMED as you can read in other answers. There is no possible way to check if the process that I wanted to kill was killed or not, because in theory, another process can be spawned right away, with same parameters and same PID. So either I get syslog flooded, or I get 1 line per kill but possibility that some of the kills wouldn't be logged at all

Comment: You seem to think I don't understand but I do.  There is no perfect solution.  All I am saying is don't make the perfect the enemy of the good.  In linux, at least, pids will be assigned sequentially so unless the system is spinning out processes at a prodigious rate (so the pid ctr wraps around) *and* your killed process dies and the pid is reassigned in the window between the kill and confirming the original process no longer exists *and* the new process is the same program with the same parameters there isn't a problem.  This is a vanishingly small possibility but still possible.

Comment: Your choices are to create a flood of meaningless log msgs (and kill signals) or for the cost of a little extra code make a reasonable effort (e.g. does the process have the original resource usage characteristics that made you want to kill it in the first place) and log what you can.

Answer (score 0):

- when you spawn these processes, the classical `waitpid(2)` family can be used
- when not used anywhere else, you can move the processes going to be killed into an own cgroup; there can be notifiers on these cgroups which get triggered when process is exiting.
- to find out, whether process has been killed, you can `chdir(2)` into `/proc/<pid>` or `open(2)` this directory.  After process termination, the status files there can not be accessed anymore.  This method is racy (between your check and the action, the process can terminate and a new one with the same pid be spawned).